# Make the child div as inline?

Tags: html, css

I have the below code

```css
input.check{
          display: inline;
        }
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.check{
  float: left;
  }
input.check{
  display: inline;
}
#parent { overflow: hidden }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" >
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <div >
                ENTER x:-
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div  >
                ENTER y:-
                <input type="text">
            </div>
            <div id="parent">
                ENTER from and to
                <br>
                <div class="check">
                FROM:-
                <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="check">
                TO:-
                <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                SEARCH COLUMNS:-
                <input id="columns" type="text">
           </div>
        </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you run this code you see that textbox for "from" and "to" is going below them, even though I have tried to make them inline with the  default display is "inline-block" through css(`input[type=text]`). I want others to be as it is but the for "from" and "to" it needs to go after the labels like inline elements.
Thank you! and please let me know the reason why I am not able to override the  display property

Comment: You have a div with class "check", not an input..

Comment: your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1yvdw7te/ if the width is big enough

Comment: "input[type=text]" has "width: 100%;", so it takes all width of parent. Try with less width. Plus, I'm not sure sure why you are using "float: left" on ".check".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace CSS for **.check** class

```
 .check{
    float: left;
 }

with

 .check {
     float: left;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you code:

```
input.check{
  display: inline;
}
```

will not work because `input.check` actually means and `input` element which also has a class of `check` but none of your input element has class of `check` in html.

If you want label and input to sit on same line and don't want to use `flex` this is what you can do:

```
.check > input {    
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
}
```

with `flexbox`:

```
.check {
     float: left;
     width: 200px;  /* <== as you wish */
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
 }

 .check > input {
   flex: 1
 }
```